# In C# Is using private constant strings better than using strings directly in the code?

Tags: c#, strings, const

Consider the following two cases:

- case 1:

  ```
  class A
  {
      private const string MyConst="Hello";

      internal void CallMe()
      {
          System.Console.WriteLine(MyConst);
      }
  }
  ```
- Case2:

  ```
  class A
  {
      internal void CallMe()
      {
          System.Console.WriteLine("Hello");
      }      
  }
  ```

Now if the CallMe() method would be called 1000 times, is it a good idea to define it as a constant (which means only one copy of the string per class) or using a plain string would be better. I just checked the MSIL code for both the classes and found that in both cases, .Net compiler is putting the string literal inside WiriteLine(). Then is it an overhead to define the string as a constant?

The main reason I asked this question was because I wanted to understand how CLR works when something is defined as a constant at the class level and when I saw that the MSIL code had const field as well as the string in WriteLine() replaced with the actual string so I was wondering why create constant field  if it will be used in only one method. This is just a sample code I wrote to present my doubt.And from the responses I learnt following:

- It's better to use the string directly if it won't be used outside the method
- If it's used throughout the class/classes then declare it as constant at the class level
- Put it in resex if it needs localization

Thanks all for responses/comments.

Comment: what do you mean by "better"?

Comment: better in terms of memory usage and performance?

Comment: You've already observed that the generated IL is identical, clearly the performance of identical IL is identical. "Better" in programming can also mean easier on you

Comment: Agreed that if IL is identical then performance will be same but then does declaring the constants is an overhead? Because these constants will be in heap all the time and I do not see much benefit here of using constants.

Comment: I didn't check, but I bet that if the compiler is smart enough to inline the constants value, he's also smart enough not to keep their initialization (in the heap or wherever), as it becomes useless.

Comment: Consider this: You continue writing, with "Hello" used all over your class. Next week, you are asked for a Spanish version, so you have to replace "Hello" with "Hola" everywhere, vs once in the constant

Comment: You are micro-optimising. Is your app running too slowly, or using too many resources? If so, profile it, identify the problems and fix them. Until then, write easy-to-read and maintain code. As @Caleth says, the *only* thing you should be considering at this stage is whether the string is used more than once. If it is, make it a constant. If it needs to support more than one language, make it a resource. To reiterate: absolutely do not try to outsmart the compiler at this sort of level by worrying about speed and memory.

Comment: Thanks @Caleth and David Arno. I am trying here to understand what CLR does. I do understand if the string is used at multiple places then it makes total sense to use one reference string for better maintenance. Anyways I am clear that if the string is used only once, it's better not to make it a constant.

Comment: [Is micro-optimisation important when coding?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/99445/is-micro-optimisation-important-when-coding)

Comment: a string literal is actually a constant. There is nothing more constant than a string literal hardcoded, it won't change at runtime, it's a fixed value ...a constant.
I agree with the idea of favouring readability, and a value that it's gonna be used only once it's more readable as a string literal than as a constant whose value I have to chase somewhere else. Case 2 is "better"

Comment: I created a post about this dilemma and explore the Common Intermediate Language (which is identical by the way). The short answer: whatever improves readability. The long answer here: https://www.diegodrivendesign.com/2018/09/constant-declarations-vs-hard-coded.html

Answer (score 11):

As covered doing this as a performance thing is not sensible. However doing it for code readability is very sensible. In a non trivial bit of code I would use constants to add syntactic meaning to the variable. Fear the magic string.

```
class GreetingPrinter
    {
        private const string Greeting = "Hello";

        internal void CallMe()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Greeting);
        }
    }
```

The `c_str` prefix makes my eyes break and adds nothing to the readability of the code.

Comment: I personally like to use such prefixes which helps in understanding what type of variable it is from any part of the code where "c" stands for constant and "str" tells its datatype.

Comment: It is a free world, however you are in a minority. Microsoft's guidelines state "**X DO NOT** use Hungarian notation." https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229045.aspx So something to think about if you are going to have other more standard developers read and understand your code.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I was not aware that Microsoft has recommended to not use Hungarian notation.

Comment: Nothing is stopping me from using a `int c_strMyConst`, which is one of the reasons the Hungarian notation  shouldn't be used. That is ofc one example that wont hurt you much as you will very fast find out that the string is actually a int. But in a C++ application with dozens of different stringtypes - bstr, cstr, 8bit per char, 16 bit per char, etc., accidentally misnaming a variable instead of relying on the typeinfo from IDE can create hours of hurt.

Comment: The correctness of this answer would become much more evident if you consider that instead of "Hello", the string could be "Χαίρετε".  Do you have the slightest clue what `Console.WriteLine("Χαίρετε")` does?  You would have to know Greek to be able to tell that it is a greeting like "Hello".

Comment: An observation on the conversation between @GawdePrasad and Froome: the biggest problem of whatever coding style guideline is that it discourages people from using their own judgement. Saying "a big-name company recommends doing this" (tends to) automatically win the debate, without even discussing pros and cons. That is sad.

Comment: I can understand using hungarian notation for non static languages but personally I would not use it. However in statically typed languages the biggest arguments are maintenance, and breaking the DRY principle. Both are a no go for me...

Comment: Conversation deviated a bit from original question about where to declare string constants. You can give semantic meaning to local a string constant too.

Answer (score 10):

Case2 is better because the string has no more than the scope it needs and I don't have to chase variables to read your code. Simple. Performance doesn't matter here.

Comment: I don't agree unconditionally but this IS a good point I think many people miss. If anything, I'd prefer putting the constant on the line above the call to the console. That way you get semantics without bloating your class.

Comment: @kai If its usefully namable that's right. Also, for max brownie points, I don't mind tracing into a resx file for this sort of thing.

Comment: If it's worth doing, it's worth doing right, eh? ;)

Answer (score 2):

To put it slightly in another direction:

In case of `Hello` it is nonsense to define a constant and I would go for the second solution. But say you have `deoxyribonucleicacid` and use it more than once in a class, I would opt for a constant, so you could leverage the IDE / compiler to do your spellchecking. I find that always a nice trick.

Comment: And you should immediately update your code to `Deoxyribonucleic` as the `deso-` prefix has not been used since... the fifties probably.

Answer (score 2):

I largely agree with Froome's answer and would do something similar in most cases, but I think there are some other things to consider:

For values that only exist in the current method, don't pull the out into a field without thinking. Keep data close to where it used and extract things when it's needed to prevent duplication. the Single Responsibility Principle tells us to keep things together that change for the same reason and to separate things that change for different reasons. This makes it easier to extract behaviors from this class into new classes as the complexity of your system grows.

To me it all depends on what kind of string "Hello" is. If it's a greeting to be output to a user in a GUI it should be pulled out into an external resource. If it's some default value returned by the method used by other methods inside the class, I'd say leave it in the method until you find a compelling reason to move it out of there.

In short, don't assume too much before you know how the value will be used. See where your design takes you and constantly evaluate if you're going in the right direction.

EDIT:

Another thought, if we consider the Open/Closed principle something like this might be appropriate:

```
public class A
{
    internal void CallMe()
    {
        Console.Out.WriteLine(GetGreeting());
    }

    protected virtual string GetGreeting()
    {
        return "Hello";
    }
}
```

This allows the behavior to be changed by extending the class but keeping this version closed for modifications.

Again, whether or not this is the way to go depends on what type of system you are building and how it will be used/changed in the future.